# Can't echo code correctly. CSS dissapears

Tags: javascript, php, output, embed, view-source

I want to make an email-signature page with Elementor and then generate the HTML-code like the code when you that appears when you "View Source" of a page, but code gets not exactly correct. I am using a Custom post type and a Elementor template that is not published so it works only when writing: https://mysite123123.com/a/site/?theme_template_id=1164

I have a PHP snippet plugin and this code gets the Post type HTML but not the same like when you press rightclick/View Source. (Its missing some css etc)

Can you see what Im doing wrong or if you know how to echo the correct html from a webpage like a regular visitor see it?

(Im using this code to give a user a HTML signature)

```
<?php
global $wp;
$vpost = get_post($post_id);
$urlcard = $vpost->post_name;
$current_url =  home_url( $wp->request );

$data = file_get_contents("https://mysite123123.com/a/".$urlcard."/?theme_template_id=1164");
$html_encoded = htmlentities($data);
echo $html_encoded;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the browser how it should render your data using a [Content-Type HTTP Response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type).

To have your data rendered as plain text -- as the 'View source' view does -- use "text/plain" as mime-type;

```php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
echo $data
```